# UIButton with changing images when pressed - but unattractive effect when changing them

Tags: iphone, image, uibutton

I have a button that changes its image to different images depending on what modus we are in.

The images are set with:`[modusBtn setImage:cx forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

The images have round corners and the button is of Type "Custom".

Now when the button is pressed one can see another image in the upper and lower edge background.

Really weird - the buttons ALL have round corners - but for example when the blue modus is on and shows the blue image and one presses the blue button now - one can see red little edges only on the left two corners.

I already played around with all the button attribute settings in IB, but no luck.

Did anyone have a similar experience when changing button images?

So far all my button images where 100% rectangular and did not have round corners - therefore I never experienced this before.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this UIButton's propriety for your button.

```
    avatarButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: Add this property also -> [button sizeToFit]; And also,I want to know where you are setting images (means in xib or through code). I think you may set one images as backgroundImage.(sorry if i am wrong,I just guessing!!!). Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the idea - the problem is gone - but the button is too large now. By the way I now also just copied the exactly same button from another working ViewControllerA to the ViewControllerB with the problem and really strangly enough it causes the same problem as the previous button only on the ViewControllerB. On ViewControllerA everything is fine. I dont have any idea what is going on here....

Comment: I changed my code now from setImage: to setBackgroundImage - and everything is OK now. Thanks very much for your hint!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you set an image for custom button make sure to set

```
yourButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
```

The effect was happening as your button was using default background transitions during changing the state.